# Nodejs webstorm socket.io wont start in debug mode

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webstorm, debug-mode

I have a nodejs application and its working with socket.io
I have the currect configuration in webstorm
when running the application it works and show in console: info - socket.io started

but when starting application in debug mode, wont show this line and socket does not start

whats the problem?

evebn thought I have nodemon and in nodemon this happens the same

Comment: does your application spawn any child processes? Try adding 'process.execArgv = [];' to the very top of your main application file - does it help? Also, what Node.js version do you use?

Comment: I added this code to top of my source. but again has the problem. my nodejs version is 0.12.0 and webstorm version is 6.0.1

Comment: I'm not sure if WebStorm 6 can be used for debugging with Node 0.12 - it's a way too old. Note also that this NodeJS version is known for bad debugging performance - starting application in debug mode usually takes minutes (see https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/877)

Comment: I'm going to get webstorm last version. maybe it will solve my problem. but for cheking nodejs version, downgraded to version 8 which I before used. but in didn't worked for me. maybe its socket problem. hope new webstorm solve my problem.